# expanding group from an Exchange Contact Group with Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Im not sure if I am going slightly mad, but I am sure in a previous version of Outlook you were able to add a contact group to an email or calendar appointment and then click on a `+` button that would then break it down to the individuals emails, for you to then edit the final list of people the artifact would be sent to.

I have tried a few things, but I cannot get a copy of the names in the contact group.

I need to get hold of these names to send to a decision maker to allow us to clean up the group. I have asked someone with admin rights on the group to get me the names, but this is very convoluted and not a very high priority.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system administrator prevented users from seeing this group's members.